# MySQL using Joins

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database, one is `articles` and the other one is `articleMedia` the `article` table stores the title and body while the `articleMedia` stores attachments, each article can have arbitrary number of attachments, the `articleMedia`table relate with the `articles` table using a foreign key which is the artcle's id, so my table structure looks like

Article table

```
----------------------------------
|id |title | body                |
----------------------------------
|1  |houses|some houses are green|
```

ArticleMedia table

```
----------------------------------
|id |articleFk | path             |
----------------------------------
|1  |2         |/media/1.jpg      |
|2  |2         |/media/house.mp4  |
```

my query skills are not so good so my query is

```
SELECT 
  article_tbl.id, title,body, articleMedia_tbl.path
FROM `article_tbl` 
JOIN articleMedia_tbl ON article_tbl.id = articleMedia_tbl.articleFk
```

which outputs something like

```
------------------------------------------------------
|id | title | body | path         |                  |
------------------------------------------------------
|1  |houses|some houses are green |/media/1.jpg      |
------------------------------------------------------
|2  |houses|some houses are green |/media/house.mp4  |
```

is there a way to avoid the duplication or what better approach can I use to avoid all this?

Comment: As far as a SQL result set is concerned, that is not duplication. How would you like the result to be structured?  Please post a sample of the output you want to achieve. Typically it is necessary to use application code to reformat a SQL result to anything besides a 2D structure of columns/rows.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to get from your query? It is not duplicating since path are distinct values.

Comment: am not trying to get anything special but my concern is, is there a better way of getting the attachments than having to have that sort of duplication where title and body are duplicated?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes I know, but if it was in your case how would you get the attachments without having to load the duplicate title and body?

Comment: Then don't select the title and body in the beginning of the SQL statement instead. Maybe use the PK as a reference to the article instead.

Comment: @Chrome If you just want title and body, use DISTINCT keyword and it will only show you once. But if you add path into context that means you are not trying to view two separate records because the paths are different.

Comment: @Chrome to make a suggestion, we need to see a sample of how you want the output to look. You could, for example, use `GROUP_CONCAT(path)` to create a comma-separated list of `path` values in one row, if you excluded the `id`, but you cannot generate a nested structure.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

What duplicationale you referring to? You appear to have a 1:N relationship where articles can have any number of media. By Joining Articles to Media you associate the two *where they match*. For each fk in the media table, you have a match in the article table, hence the duplication; your query is doing exactly what you want. You could hide the duplication by altering your projection (selected columns) with just the ones you want to see.

What I *think* you are touching on is the more interesting danger of JOINS, that is a CROSS JOIN. At it's heart, a join represents the cartesian product of two tables. We only join at most a 1:N relationship, because we can accept the need for the data duplication from the 1 side. If we joined N:N we would end up with every combination between the two (e.g. A:A, A:B, B:A, B:B, etc). This can be solved with an associative entity.

To be clear, you do not have a cartesian join here, however, I found this helpful in my understanding of joins:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3901221/Identifying-and-Eliminating-the-Dreaded-Cartesian-Product.htm